# Google Scholar: how to request indexing of well-known conference

Tags: conference, google-scholar, open-access, proceedings

I realized that Google hasn't properly indexed the well-known "Extending Database Technology" (EDBT) conference of 2019. The proceedings are uploaded via OpenProceedings and are usually indexed by Google Scholar.

Is there a "proper way" to request (re-)indexing? I am somewhat surprised to see that for many papers only privately hosted and outdated Arxiv versions are listed, while the EDBT conference is one of few exceptions with its fully open proceedings.

Comment: You can't! The algorithm is quite complex, eventually it will get indexed automatically.

Comment: https://scholar.google.com/intl/en/scholar/inclusion.html#crawl

Comment: Well, "eventually" three years later? :(

Comment: @HermanToothrot obscure \neq complex. Do not bow to the might reputation of the bigggest advertising company of the world, Alphabet.